# How to solve "Error in date in query expression "

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a code to insert `Now()` in unbound combo box but when I load my form I get a syntax error in date.

My date is in format `dd.mm.yyyy` and need this format not US format. If I set regional settings to match Windows which is US then everything is working perfectly but need my regional settings because of other applications and statistics.

Code:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cboDate_AfterUpdate()
'check if we can evaluate cboDate into a date
    If IsDate(Me.cboDate) Then
        Call LoadData(Me.cboDate)
    End If
    End Sub

Public Function LoadData(strDate As String)
On Error Goto Err_Handler
    If DCount("1", "Food_Distribution", "FD_Date=#" & strDate & "#") > 0 Then
        'do nothing
    Else
              
    CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into Food_Distribution (fd_date, ID_Number, first_name, last_name, gender) " & _
            "select #" & strDate & "#, ID_Number, first_name, last_name, gender From tblFD;"
  
  End If
Exit_here:
    Exit Function
    
Err_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
    Resume Exit_here
End Function

Public Function TryToCorrectDate(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim v As Variant
    v = Split(s, "/")
    If v(0) > 12 Then
        TryToCorrectDate = v(1) & "/" & v(0) & "/" & v(2)
    Else
        TryToCorrectDate = s
    End If
End Function


Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.cboDate = Date$
    
    'save the record
    Call LoadData(Date$)
End Sub
```

Comment: _See screenshot of my code._ ... please include code (and error messages) as formatted text in your question. Content of images cannot be searched.

Comment: As you've been told you need to post your code as text, as well as any error code you get and an explanation on how your out differs from the expected one. I've edited the question to show the image, in the meantime.

Comment: I have uploaded a code and erorr message is: Run-time error 3075    Syntax error in date in query expression 'FD_Date=#02/07/2020.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware, that combobox items always are text. Thus, its value must be converted to a date value, as dates always should be handled as dates, not text, not numbers.

Then you get something like this:

```vb
Private Sub cboDate_AfterUpdate()

    'check if we can evaluate cboDate into a date
    If IsDate(Me.cboDate) Then
        ' Convert text date to date value.
        Call LoadData(DateValue(Me.cboDate))
    End If

End Sub


Public Function LoadData(ThisDate As Date)

    Dim strDate As String

    On Error Goto Err_Handler

    ' Create string expression for the date value.
    strDate = Format(ThisDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
    If DCount("1", "Food_Distribution", "FD_Date = #" & strDate & "#") > 0 Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into Food_Distribution (fd_date, ID_Number, first_name, last_name, gender) " & _
            "select #" & strDate & "#, ID_Number, first_name, last_name, gender From tblFD;"
    End If

Exit_here:
    Exit Function
    
Err_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
    Resume Exit_here
End Function


Private Sub Form_Load()

    ' Apply the format of the combobox to the date value.
    Me!cboDate.Value = Format(Date, Me!cboDate.Format)
    
    'save the record
    Call LoadData(Date)

End Sub
```

Comment: I have changed as you suggested but getting error in VBA console: Call LoadData(DateValue(Me.cboDate)) and on open form I get error "The expression you enterd as query parameter produced this error 'FD_Date'

Comment: I am sorry it was a typo error. Your code is working perfectly. Thank you so much, you are the man for me. Bless you

Comment: Click the checkmark at left under the voting count.